# server response in ajax goes in error function instead of success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have seen many solution for the above question but none of them falls in my category. My server is responding with correct json. Not able to figure what is exactly causing the issue. I get status as 0 and status text as error . Its disgusting . Issue is in deleteimage() function. There mi8 be issue in a way i am handling event.If anyone can figure out it would be good.Almost a day gone after this. Help is appreciated.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    //grab all form data  
        var form = $('#get_design_form');

        form.submit(function(event) {                   
            event.preventDefault();         
            var x = true;


            if(category_id.value == '0'){
                alert("Please select category.");
                category_id.focus();
                x=false;
                return x;
            }

            if(design_no.value == ''){
                alert("Please enter design no.");
                design_no.focus();
                x=false;
                return x;
            }



            if (x) {
                $('#send').attr("disabled",true);
                $('#lm').show();
                $.ajax({
                    type: form.attr('method'),
                    url: form.attr('action'),
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    success : function(data) {
                        var result = data;


                        if(result.response_code=='101'){
                            $('#failure').show();
                            $('#success').hide();
                            $('#failure').text("Error Occured.Try again");
                        }else if(result.response_code=='102'){
                            $('#failure').show();
                            $('#success').hide();
                            $('#failure').text("Design no. does not exist.");
                        }else{
                            $('#con2').show();
                            $('#con1').hide();

                            $('#category_name').val(result.design_details.category_id);                         
                            $('#des_no').val(result.design_details.design_no);

                            //$('#image').attr('src','downloadImage?image_name='+result.design_img);

                            for(i=0;i<result.design_details.list_design_img.length;i++){

                                var html='<img id="'+result.design_details.list_design_img[i].design_img_path.split(".")[0]+'" src=downloadImage?image_name='+result.design_details.list_design_img[i].design_img_path+' style="vertical-align:middle;" width="100" height="100">';

                                var html1='<span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="javascript:deleteimage(\'' + result.design_details.list_design_img[i].design_img_path + '\',\'' + result.design_details.category_id + '\',\'' + result.design_details.design_no + '\')">X</span>';


                                $('#img_div').append(html);
                                $('#img_div').append(html1);

                            }


                        }               
                        $('#lm').hide();
                        $('#send').attr("disabled",false);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
                        //return false;
        $('#send').attr("disabled", false);
        $('#lm').hide();
    });


<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteimage(image_name,category_id,design_no)
{
    alert("hii"+image_name+","+category_id+","+design_no);
    var answer = confirm ("Are you sure you want to delete?");


    if (answer)
    {   
            $.ajax({                    
                    url: "http://192.168.0.2:8080/JaydeepSarees/deleteOthersDesignImgPath",
                    data: jQuery.param({image_name: image_name,category_id: category_id,design_no: design_no}) ,
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                    type: "post",                   
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("hii");
                        var result=data;
                        alert(result.response_code);
                        if (result.response_code == 100) {
                            alert(result.response_code);
                            $("#"+image_name).remove();
                        }                     
                    },error: function (jqXHR,exception) {

                        console.log(jqXHR);                     
                        var msg = '';
                        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                            msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.'+jqXHR.statusText;
                        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                            msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                            msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                            msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                            msg = 'Time out error.';
                        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                            msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                        } else {
                            msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                        }

                        alert(msg);
                    }
                });
      }
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: The `error` handler is hit when the server does *not* return a `200 OK` HTTP status code. Therefore the problem is in your server code, not the JS. use the network tab of the console to see the exact response text (hopefully the server will give you a meaningful error to diagnose) and to ensure the values you're sending in the request are correct.

Comment: i am getting 200 OK.

Comment: The error handler has arguments that will tell you what kind of error it is.

Comment: That's not possible if you're going in to the `error` handler

Comment: It not only when is not 200 OK, could be 200 OK but jQuery can reject for bad response format. Check that you inserted correctly "accept" and content-type parameters both on server and client side with "application/json".

Comment: can you 
                        console.log(jqXHR, exception);  and show the result in here?

Comment: my server returns {"response_code":"100"} which is correct json.

Comment: @Vladimir M it prints  [object Object]error

Comment: When i run my WebService in postman it runs properly.Gives me response as {"response_code":"100"} . Which means there is some mistake in event handling by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use an relative path when trying to send request to server where in i was using absolute path that was the reason i was getting status as 0.

```
url: "deleteOthersDesignImgPath"
```

instead of

```
url: "http://192.168.0.2:8080/JaydeepSarees/deleteOthersDesignImgPath",
```